# Process.start() not working on iis

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, web-applications, process.start

I have been working on a FileSearch web app using asp.net VB, on a button click the program should open a file(.txt/.pdf). when running the code locally the file opens normally but when the program is running on IIS the program fails to open the file. the exception that the program is giving me is either "the process "###" is not found " or "thread failed to start". I would appreciate it so much if someone helped!! 
below is the code I am using.
thank you in advance

```
 Protected Sub OpenBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenBTN.Click
    Try
        FinalFile = dir & Field2.ToString() & "\" & DateList.SelectedItem.Text & "\" & AccList.SelectedItem.Text
        Label2.Text = FinalFile 'FinalFile is the path'
        Dim P = Process.Start(FinalFile)


    Catch ex As Exception

        filee.Text = ex.Message 'this is showiing me the exception'
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Starting a process on a server is usually not permitted. And even if it were you would only open a document on the server itself, not the client.

Comment: @VDWWD thank you, but is there a way that could be done?

Comment: No, you will have to rethink your approach.

Comment: The file search will search the files on the web server. Is that what you intend? If yes, then we can work with that.

Comment: You should drop the seperated application for searching files and move that code to the ASP.NET application. Then you don't need to execute an external application.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You don't know much about the basics of IIS so time to study that. Then you will see why others commented that you need to switch to another approach.